# How to store texts from text file in json format with Perl

Tags: json, perl

I would like to know how to store texts from a text file in Json format with Perl.

Texts from text file

```
23rd Street Wave the Wheat Ale

Lawrence, Kansas, USA

5.2

13.65

Rating - 0.00

3 Guys & A Beerâ€™d Wheat the People

Carbondale, Pennsylvania, USA

5.2

Unknown

Rating - 0.00

51 North Paint Creek Wheat

Lake Orion, Michigan, USA

4.8

Unknown

Rating - 0.00
```

I had tried to implement codes but it failed, because I found that perl can read file using while loop on the internet.

Below is my Perl scripting

```
for($i = 0; $i < $fileSize; $i+2){
say qq{{"beerName": "$beerName", 
"location":"$location",
"ABV":"$ABV",
"IBU":"$IBU",
"Rating":"$Rating"}};
}
```

Comment: Use a module, [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/JSON-2.94/lib/JSON.pm)

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? What happens when you run your program? What did you expect to happen instead? Post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm confused... You ask for help storing data, but you show a text file instead of a data structure?!

Comment: ...Is your problem actually an inability to parse your text file?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I need to parse text into JSON array format, but I have no idea how to do it. I'm thinking of using data structure, will it make sense for it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the structure of your text file is and how consistent it is.  I think every entry is 5 lines long, with each entry's items in the same order.  If that's the case, maybe one way to do it is to read the text file in 5 lines at a time, assign each line to the appropriate hash key, and then store that hash ref in an array that we can later use for the JSON structure.  Maybe a more elegant way to do it, but what about something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use JSON;

my $input_file = shift;
my @results;

open(my $fh, "<", $input_file);
# Read the text file 5 lines at a time, and store each line in the hash data with the desired keys.
while ( (my @lines) = map { scalar(<$fh>) or () } 0..4 ) {
    my %data = ('beername' => $lines[0],
                'location' => $lines[1],
                'ABV'      => $lines[2],
                'IBU'      => $lines[3],
                'Rating'   => $lines[4],
    );
    # Store these hash refs in an array that we'll later convert to JSON.
    push(@results, \%data);
}

# Write results to file.
open(my $json_out, ">", 'beers.json');
print {$json_out} encode_json(\@results);
```

This will result in a "beers.json" file that will have the structure:

```
$ json_xs <beers.json
[
   {
      "ABV" : "5.2\n",
      "IBU" : "13.65\n",
      "location" : "Lawrence, Kansas, USA\n",
      "Rating" : "Rating - 0.00\n",
      "beername" : "23rd Street Wave the Wheat Ale\n"
   },
   {
      "ABV" : "5.2\n",
      "IBU" : "Unknown\n",
      "location" : "Carbondale, Pennsylvania, USA\n",
      "Rating" : "Rating - 0.00\n",
      "beername" : "3 Guys & A BeerÃ¢â¬â¢d Wheat the People\n"
   },
   {
      "location" : "Lake Orion, Michigan, USA\n",
      "Rating" : "Rating - 0.00\n",
      "beername" : "51 North Paint Creek Wheat\n",
      "IBU" : "Unknown\n",
      "ABV" : "4.8\n"
   }
]
```

Like I said, maybe not elegant and completely dependent upon the assumption that your file is 5 lines long for each beer and the metadata for each beer is in the same order each time.  But, if nothing else, this can possibly serve as a good starting point?

Comment: Thx, that's what I want, sorry to the people who try to solve this, I will improve myself in asking question.